# Fetching an admin URL from frontend

Tags: admin, adminhtml, frontend

I am trying to access an admin routed url from a frontend routed URL using curl.  I do the following:

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.com/index.php/admin/mycache/verify/');
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $_COOKIE['adminhtml']);
            $Verify = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            echo "V: $Verify";
```

The idea here is that I want that url to return a 1 if the user is logged into the admin part of my site, and anything else otherwise.  When I do the above though, even though the adminhtml cookie is set, curl never gets the data from that URL.  Can someone explain why and/or how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following -

```
$sesId = isset($_COOKIE['adminhtml']) ? $_COOKIE['adminhtml'] : false ;
$session = false;
if($sesId){
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_session')->read($sesId);
}
$loggedIn = false;
if($session)
{
    if(stristr($session,'Mage_Admin_Model_User'))
    {
        $loggedIn = true;
    }
}
var_dump($loggedIn);
```

This will be true if admin logged in and false if not. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Does "Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_session')->read($sesId);" only return a session if there is a real session and not just a spoofed cookie?